# My homepage wordpress is always redirected to another page

Tags: wordpress

So, I just move my wordpress file from a folder called 'md' in public_html into index of public_html. I've change the value of siteurl and homeurl in database (wp_options) from https://klinikmydentist.com/md/ into https://klinikmydentist.com/ . But, my homepage is always redirected to https://klinikmydentist.com/md/ . Only in homepage. Another page works normally.

Comment: Clear you cache then check. i have checked https://klinikmydentist.com/ and it not redirect to https://klinikmydentist.com/md   so clearing your cache.

Comment: I see.Thanks bro

Comment: Is your problem resolved now?

Answer (score 0):

Pro tip for the future: when you are moving a Wordpress site, the best practice (at least in my experience) is to download your database from PHPMyAdmin (or whatever you are using), put it into a text editor, do a command or control F, search for any instance of the old location, and replace them with where you are moving the new site. Once you've done that just re-upload the file back into your PHPMyAdmin or whatever, and move the site to the new location.

Be careful though, if you have links to the original site location in posts or pages, and don't want those to change as well, you'll have to go in one by one and replace the old locations. This rarely is an issue though so I wouldn't worry too much about it.